# Ошибка при работе с редис laravel docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, redis

Пытаюсь запихнуть сессию и кеш в редис, при обновлении страницы получаю ошибку:

```
Predis\Connection\ConnectionException
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known [tcp://redis:6379]
```

.env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

docker-compose.yml

```
redis:
 image: redis:6.0
 ports:
  - "63791:6379"
 restart: always

php-fpm:
    container_name: fpm
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    - ./docker/php-fpm/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    links:
      - mysql
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=mysql"
      - "ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=elasticsearch:9200"
      - "REDIS_PORT=6379"
      - "REDIS_HOST=redis"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - frontend-network
      - backend-network
```

config/database.php все по умолчанию за исключением

```
        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),
```

Поменял на predis, ну и соответственно predis установлен через компосер.

Редис контейнер работает нормально, подключался к нему и проверял команду `ping` через `redis-cli` в ответ получил `pong`

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы указали что PHP-FPM слинкован(links) с MySQL и ES, но не добавили туда Redis. Либо поставьте Redis на одну из тех же сетей (networks) что и PHP-FPM.

Comment: В сетях дело было, если хотите добавьте ответ по сетям я приму его

Comment: Я не знал точно, так что можете самостоятельно добавить ответ.

Comment: в сервисе `redis` `docker-compose.yml` добавь сеть приложения (наверное `backend-network`)

Comment: Да Максим все верно, если хотите добавьте ответ я его приму как решение вопроса.